# Best way to track a user on a site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, state

I was reading on session state, application state, cookies, profiles.. and i wondered way would i adapt to my site.

I am building a forum, and i need to check whether the user is logged in or not. If he is not logged in, he wont have the choices a logged user has (e.g. pressing the reply/start thread/submit messages  buttons). Basically, i thought to plant a cookie onto the users pc..but some browsers dont allow cookies, then i thought i would follow with a session state for users who dont allow cookies. I looked at the modes of the session configuration that session state has got, and there was one that i liked.. it was mode="sqlServer", but then i read that it has a disadvantage of being slow, and that i need to install a few more components to make it work.. in other words it looks cumbersome. I also looked at profile option, and i think it is a solution.. as soon as the user logs in, i can set his name. Something along those lines:

```
  protected void updateProfileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Profile.Name = nameTextBox.Text;
    Profile.Age = Int16.Parse(ageTextBox.Text);
  }
```

Whats the best option that i have got,? i am thinking of using cookies in a combination with profiling!!

Comment: Session needs a way to track the user too. Either by cookie or by a url parameter. With cookie being much nicer.

Comment: url paramenter isnt so reliable..what if it will come up in googles results and a few users will enter the same page? url also gets reset when a user leaves the page. Cookie is nice..but some users dont allow cookies on their browsers!!

Comment: What else would you propose? All other mechanism I can think of are even worse. In my websites I use cookies and if the user doesn't accept them, he can't log in.

Comment: lol.... why profile method cant help.. it is used for setting preferences..so why cant i embed id or password there?!?

Comment: And how do you expect asp.net to recognize the user if not with a cookie/url parameter? Profile, Session etc are just high level APIs.

Comment: if i use Form Authentication,,which deposits a cookie.. how do i retrieve it ID number..or store one of its parameters/identification attributes, into my sql. Does an Authentication Form cookie has a pass/hashcode/id that i can save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to have a mechanism to allow a user to access additional functionality when they are logged in then have a look at ASP.NET Forms Authentication:

> [ASP.NET Forms Authentication Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx)

**Update:**

In answer to the two questions in the comment below:

> should i set this user identity to the
>   cookie? User.Identity.Name;

No, once you've authenticated the user ASP.NET's Forms Authentication provider configures the cookie for you.

> will it add an automatic password to
>   the web.config?

No it won't, you need to write your own mechanism to store a user's details which would typically be captured from a user registration page (e.g. username, password, name, age, etc) For example you can use a SQL or Access database or you could use the ASP.NET Membership provider:

> [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)

Comment: Thanks i looked into it. I used FormsAuthenticationModule. should i set this user identity to the cookie?  User.Identity.Name; .. and will it add an automatic password to the web.config..like in the example:      <user name="Kim"
              password="07B7F3EE06F278DB966BE960E7CBBD103DF30CA6"/>

Comment: i am reading about security now. I do need some ID for my sql querries. So if the Authentication provider configures it to me.. how do i get it?